# Can you extract image data of street views from Google Maps?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api

I require a dataset that contains images of building facades in the city of Glasgow.

I understand that I could either photograph them myself or screenshot them from Google Street View.

Is there a method of extracting these images from an API using Python?

I need images like this:

[image]

Comment: You can find information about the [Google StreetView API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/overview) but use is limited by the [terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/). An alternative source with a more open (CC BY-SA) license for images is [mapillary](https://www.mapillary.com/app/?lat=55.862494485178274&lng=-4.260204436498952&z=14), which has an [API](https://www.mapillary.com/developer/api-documentation) too. In Python I'd recommend the [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to make API requests.